# R: Merging all s4 objects of a list into one

Tags: r, list, spatial

A have a list called dataall that is consisted of 47 S4 objects (from [[1]] to [[47]]).

These objects contain x,y coordinates.

When executing command:

```
class(dataall)
```

I'm receiving this message:

> [1] "list"

while executing

```
class(dataall[[1]])
```

> "Spatial Points" 
>   attr(, "package") 
>   [1] "sp"

What I would like to do is to save all these coordinates to a single list, or a single dataframe.

Comment: have you tried: `library(dplyr); bind_rows(dataall)` ?

Comment: well it returns the following message:   Argument 1 is a list, must contain atomic vectors
However the following is working:  aa <- dataall[[1]]@coords; aa <- rbind(aa, dataall[[2]]@coords).   Is there any way to get the number of s4 objects? (how many dataall[[i]] there are?) If yes I have found the solution to my problem.